# hardwiring lights to a 20 amp circuit

Tags: electrical

I have a 20 amp circuit running in my barn.  I wish to hook 3 or 4 fluorescent lights to the circuit if i can.  Each of the lights has a much smaller wire to connect to.  Can i put in a junction box and use a wire nut to connect the lights to the 12 guage wire and still use a 20 amp circuit breaker?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem doing what you want to do. These smaller wires are called "fixture wires". They're allowed to be smaller than the rest of the wiring on the circuit, because the manufacturer knows the device will consume less current than the wires can handle.